# VBA to run (premade) formulas based on active cells

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to make a formula run with VBA.  My eventual goal is to have it run multiple Formulas all with one click based off of a selected batch of cells.  For some context on what I am doing with these formulas. I am using formulas to auto generate a scope of work based on prepopulated fields.  As an example:

```
Circuit ID        scope                data1    data2   data3  data4
123                                     a        b       c      d
234                                     f        g       h      j
```

I want to highlight the circuit IDs and have the formula fill in under scope relative to the circuit IDs selected.  This is what I have so far... I used the macro recorder and it doesnt want to work.

```
Sub Formulas()
'
' Formulas Macro
'

'

    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "="•     Customer name: ""&RC[29]&"""&chr(10)&"•     Customer Bus Org: ""&RC[30]&"""&chr(10)&"•     Internal Circuit ID: ""&RC[2]&"""&chr(10)&"•     Customer prem address: ""&RC[12]&"" ""&RC[13]&"" ""&RC[14]&"", ""&RC[15]&"", ""&RC[16]&"", ""&RC[17]&"""&chr(10)&"•     Customer demarc: ""&RC[18]&"" ""&RC[20]&"", ""&RC[19]&"" ""&RC[21]&"""&chr(10)&"•     MRR: ""&RC[68]&"""&chr(10)&"•     Current Off Net MRC: $""&RC[10]&"""&chr(10)&"•   "& _
        " Percent: ""&RC[89]&"""&chr(10)&"•     Bandwidth: ""&RC[6]&"" ( ""&RC[7]&""Mb )"&chr(10)&"•     Customer term end date: ""&TEXT(RC[32],""mmm-dd-yyyy"")&"""&chr(10)&"•     New Vendor: ""&RC[106]&"""&chr(10)&"•     New MRC: $""&RC[102]&"""&chr(10)&"•     New NRC: $""&RC[103]&"""&chr(10)&"•     New Install Interval: ""&RC[105]&"""&chr(10)&"•     New Term: ""&RC[104]&"""&chr(10)&""&chr(10)&"Planner Notes:"&chr(10)&"This project is replacing the existing ""&RC[6]&"" ( "& _
        """Mb ) based solution from ( ""&RC[5]&"" ) with a new ""&RC[99]&"" ( ""&RC[100]&""Mb ) based solution from ( ""&RC[106]&"" ). "&chr(10)&""&chr(10)&"RFA # ""&RC[107]&"" install notes:"&chr(10)&"Please install ( ""&RC[31]&"" ) Ethernet ""&RC[99]&"" ( ""&RC[100]&""Mb  ) circuit with ( ""&RC[106]&"" ) from ( ""&RC[101]&"" )  to ( [Customer Prem] ""&RC[12]&"" ""&RC[13]&"" ""&RC[14]&"", ""&RC[15]&"", "& _
        "&"", ""&RC[17]&"" ).  This new circuit will be used to replace existing customer circuit ECCKT: ""&RC[1]&"", ""&RC[109]&"", ""&RC[110]&"", ICCKT: ""&RC[2]&"".  The customer prem address is ( ""&RC[12]&"" ""&RC[13]&"" ""&RC[14]&"", ""&RC[15]&"", ""&RC[16]&"", ""&RC[17]&"" ) and customer demarc is ( ""&RC[18]&"" ""&RC[20]&"", ""&RC[19]&"" ""&RC[21]&"" )."&chr(10)&""&chr(10)&""&chr(10)&"""""& _

End Sub
```

This is my actual formula and I noticed the recorder changed a lot of things.
="
-     Customer name: "&AH2&"
-     Customer Bus Org: "&AI2&"
-     Internal Circuit ID: "&G2&"
-     Customer prem address: "&Q2&" "&R2&" "&S2&", "&T2&", "&U2&", "&V2&"
-     Customer demarc: "&W2&" "&Y2&", "&X2&" "&Z2&"
-     MRR: "&BU2&"
-     Current Off Net MRC: $"&O2&"
-     Margin Percent: "&CP2&"
-     Bandwidth: "&K2&" ( "&L2&"Mb )
-     Customer term end date: "&TEXT(AK2,"mmm-dd-yyyy")&"
-     New Vendor: "&DG2&"
-     New MRC: $"&DC2&"
-     New NRC: $"&DD2&"
-     New Install Interval: "&DF2&"
-     New Term: "&DE2&"

Planner Notes:

> This project is replacing the existing "&K2&" ( "&L2&"Mb ) based
>   solution from ( "&J2&" ) with a new "&CZ2&" ( "&DA2&"Mb ) based
>   solution from ( "&DG2&" ).

RFA # "&DH2&" install notes:

> Please install ( "&AJ2&" ) Ethernet "&CZ2&" ( "&DA2&"Mb  ) circuit
>   with ( "&DG2&" ) from ( "&DB2&" )  to ( [Customer Prem] "&Q2&" "&R2&"
>   "&S2&", "&T2&", "&U2&", "&V2&" ).  This new circuit will be used to
>   replace existing customer circuit ECCKT: "&F2&", "&DJ2&", "&DK2&",
>   ICCKT: "&G2&".  The customer prem address is ( "&Q2&" "&R2&" "&S2&",
>   "&T2&", "&U2&", "&V2&" ) and customer demarc is ( "&W2&" "&Y2&",
>   "&X2&" "&Z2&" ).

"

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to use `FormulaR1C1`, not just `Formula`.

2) Do not use `Select`, instead just reference the cell directly, e.g.:

```
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=""Customer name: "" & RC[29]"
```

If the macro recorder screws things up, then just build up the formula step by step yourself. The next step would be:

```
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=""Customer name: "" & RC[29] & "" Customer Bus Org: "" & RC[30]"
```

Etc.
Etc.

3) I'd recommend using fully qualified references:

```
Sub formulas()

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test") ' change to name of your sheet

    With ws

        ' In production, you probably want to loop through the rows and insert the formula dynamically.     
        ' If so, insert loop here and reference the scope column cell dynamically instead of using range("E2")
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=""Customer name: "" & RC[29] & "" Customer Bus Org: "" & RC[30]"

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: First off thank you so much Miqi for your time.  Having a lot of fun making my head hurt trying to get this piece to work.  I got in and worked on the formula in VBA and i seem to be having issues with it running.  I feel like im just missing one little thing that my untrained eyes are missing.